# C++ Convert 3D Velocity Vector To Speed Value

Tags: c++, 3d, game-physics, trigonometry, angle

In a game I am working on I get the velocity of a game world object like so

```
void getObjectVelocity(int objectID, vec3_t *velocityOut);
```

So if I were to call this function like this

```
vec3_t storeObjectVelocity;
getObjectVelocity(21/* just an example ID */, &storeObjectVelocity);
```

The velocity of the object with the ID of 21 would be stored in `storeObjectVelocity`.

For testing purposes I am trying to print the speed of this object based off it's velocity in the middle of the game screen.

Here's an example just to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
int convertVelocityToSpeed(vec3_t velocity)
{
    //This is where I am having issues.
    //Converting the objects 3D velocity vector to a speed value
}

int testHUDS()
{
    char velocityToSpeedBuffer[32] = { 0 };
    vec3_t storeObjectVelocity;
    getObjectVelocity(21, &storeObjectVelocity);

    strcpy(velocityToSpeedBuffer, "Speed: ");
    strcat(velocityToSpeedBuffer, system::itoa(convertVelocityToSpeed(storeObjectVelocity), 10));

    render::text(SCREEN_CENTER_X, SCREEN_CENTER_Y, velocityToSpeedBuffer, FONT_SMALL);
}
```

Here is my `vec3_t` struct in case you were wondering

```
struct vec3_t
{
    float x, y, z;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Length of a vector is calculated as
√( x² + y² + z²)

So in your program, something like this will works:

```
std::sqrt( velocity.x * velocity.x + velocity.y * velocity.y + velocity.z * velocity.z )
```

As @Nelfeal commented, last approach can overflow. Using [`std::hypot`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) this problem is avoided. Since is more secure and it's clearer, this should be the first option if C++17 is available. Even knowing that it's less efficient. Remember to avoid premature micro optimizations.

```
std::hypot(velocity.x, velocity.y, velocity.z)
```

Also, you should think about passing `velocity` as a const reference to the function.

Comment: Keep in mind this can overflow. If you are sure it won't, this is fine. Otherwise, you might need `std::hypot` or something similar, even though it's slower.

Comment: @Nelfeal You are right. I added your recommendation to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Speed is a scalar quantity given by the magnitude of a velocity vector `|velocity|`. Magnitude of a 3D vector is computed as:

[image: Magnitude of vector]

So in your code you want to implement your method as:

```
int convertVelocityToSpeed(vec3_t velocity)
{
    return std::sqrt(velocity.x * velocity.x + velocity.y * velocity.y + velocity.z * velocity.z);
}
```

you may need to include the math header `#include <cmath>` and I have assumed your `vec3_t` holds `int` values although this is unusual for a velocity in physics simulations, they are usually floating point types. If not you need to check your return type.

Comment: Because you haven't tested your code before posting it? [It's not that hard](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6eb9546b6812a18). Plus, you mention a C header in a C++ question.

Comment: @Nelfeal Fair point. Fixed both. Also thank you for the link to the web app.

Comment: Also, why add two lots of `velocity.z * velocity.z`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

sqrt(pow(velocity.x,2), pow(velocity.y,2), pow(velocity.x,2));
```

Use sqrt from cmath and pow from cmath.

**EDIT**
edited the mistype import as corrected by in the comments

Comment: You sure about `import`?

Comment: If you're going to you `std::pow`, you might as well use `std::hypot`.

Comment: `import` should be `#include` surely? Also, from experience, there are performance penalties for using `pow` over directly multiplying values. Possibly something newer compilers might be better at spotting.

Comment: @CodingLumis In VS `pow` has special case when power is 2, it just multiplies the value on itself. Dunno about other compilers.

Comment: I have fixed the error. Please remove your down vote. Thanks